# running apache and rails on an ubuntu droplet

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu

at first i installed apache, and i built up some sites.

Then later I tried to install rails according to [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04), since it's made by my hosting company.

I originally wanted to install rails in a sub-directory, so that most of the pages would be served up by apache and I could just build up some special apps with rails.

At this point I've corrupted the apache pages which heretofore were working just fine.

Should I just uninstall everything and start over?

But, what is the issue, is this how rails is supposed to work? Is it hard to make it compatible with apache? Can a server run only rails, would that be easier to manage?

I also had some javascript templates running off that apache server in the beginning.

Are there some particular log files I can investigate to discern what's at fault? Where are they located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help by providing a decent tutorial on rails + apache but I can help on nginx + rails + zero downtime.

Typically the webserver `apache`, `nginx` serves as a proxy webserver. They send the request from the user through a unix domain socket to the rails application running as a separate process.

I've written a detailed tutorial on setting up a deployment server from scratch.

- [Setup a vps](https://github.com/JensDebergh/guides/blob/master/operations/server/1-setup.md)
- [Securing vps + nginx](https://github.com/JensDebergh/guides/blob/master/operations/server/2-deploy-setup.md)
- [Deploying the rails application](https://github.com/JensDebergh/guides/blob/master/operations/server/3-app-deploy.md)

Hope it helps !